# STContains returns points that are not in polygon

Tags: sql, sql-server, spatial-query

I am trying to get points from a Microsoft SQL Server table that are inside a polygon from another table.  The current query results in points outside the definition of the polygon.

The main query I have is this:

```
select top 10
          ATOMIZER.[ATOMIZER_ID]
          ,ATOMIZER.LAT
          ,ATOMIZER.LONG
          from db..ATOMIZER join db..[AOI]
          on ATOMIZER.ZIP = Cast(AOI.[zip] AS varchar)
          where 1 = CASE AOI.TYPE
          WHEN 'polygon' THEN AOI.[geography].STContains(geography::Point(ATOMIZER.LAT, ATOMIZER.LONG, 4326))
          WHEN 'rectangle' THEN AOI.[geography].STContains(geography::Point(ATOMIZER.LAT, ATOMIZER.LONG, 4326))
          WHEN 'circle' THEN AOI.[geography].STContains(AOI.[geography].STBuffer(AOI.radius)) END  
          
          and AOI.id =  {AOI} 
          --and AOI.DateLicensed is null
          and ATOMIZER.LAT is not null
          and ATOMIZER.LONG is not null
```

I have also simplified the query to this in an attempt to troubleshoot.

```
select top 10
          ATOMIZER.[ATOMIZER_ID]
          ,ATOMIZER.LAT
          ,ATOMIZER.LONG
          from db..ATOMIZER join db..[AOI]
          on ATOMIZER.ZIP = Cast(AOI.[zip] AS varchar)
  where AOI.id =  9198
  and ATTOM.LAT is not null
  and ATTOM.LONG is not null
  and AOI.geography.STContains(geography::Point(ATOMIZER.LAT, ATOMIZER.LONG, 4326)) = 1
```

The Atomizer Table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE db.dbo.ATOMIZER (
    ATOMIZER_ID bigint NULL,
    ADDRESS varchar(140) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    CITY varchar(64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    STATE varchar(8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    ZIP varchar(14) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    LAT float NULL,
    LONG float NULL,
    GEOCODE_DT date NULL,
    Geocodio_Address varchar(156) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Geocodio_City varchar(56) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Geocodio_State varchar(8) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Geocodio_Zip varchar(14) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Geocodio_Lat float NULL,
    Geocodio_Lng float NULL,
    Geocodio_GEOID varchar(26) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    Geocodio_POINT geography NULL
);
```

The AOI table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE db.dbo.AOI (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(500) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [type] varchar(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
    [geography] geography
);
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NonClusteredIndex-20221206-185336 ON dbo.AOI (  zip ASC  )  
     WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,FILLFACTOR = 100  ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF , ONLINE = OFF , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  )
     ON [PRIMARY ] ;
```

In the main query, I'm looking at AOI 9198  The polygon in the polygon in the AOI appear like this:

```
[(27.334412613029517, -82.48118404236736),
 (27.334488859974545, -82.4711418518156),
 (27.329456449106882, -82.47105602112713),
 (27.330218950286305, -82.48109821167888),
 (27.334412613029517, -82.48118404236736)]
```

However, the results for that AOI returns ATOMIZER points outside the polygon:

```
[(243854600, 27.049499, -82.139568),
 (243844656, 27.072806, -82.093464),
 (250735272, 27.299072, -82.456513),
 (145991001, 27.299082, -82.47212),
 (145943693, 27.299085, -82.47242),
 (25251051, 27.299086, -82.47049),
 (16653415, 27.29909, -82.467433),
 (10864549, 27.299091, -82.46352),
 (163778547, 27.299092, -82.465079),
 (49735501, 27.299093, -82.457673)]
```

These points lie outside the geography.
What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: In your code sample, you have `where AOI.id =  9198`, and in the text you have `I'm looking at AOI 9891`. Are you sure you're testing against the correct polygon at all times?

Comment: Yes. That was a typo here. Fixing

Comment: There is a common error in specifying geography polygon data in specifying the boundary points in the "incorrect" order such that the resulting object doesn't define the intended area but rather the entire Earth minus the intended area. As a litmus test, I often use either `EnvelopeAngle()` or `STArea()` on the polygon and look for unexpected values. Does your polygon exhibit this problem? If so, does calling `ReorientObject()` on it resolve the issue?

Comment: that was exactly the problem.  can you please put that in answer format so I can give you the points?  Thanks